# How can I connect two DVI-D monitors to my Macbook Pro (latest model)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, dvi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I plug two external monitors in to a MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/can-i-plug-two-external-monitors-in-to-a-macbook-pro)

I have two Dell DVI-D monitors that I'd like to use with my new Macbook Pro (not Retina).

I have a single DVI-D -> Mini DP adapter, but obviously that only accounts for a single monitor.

My research for a split adapter has failed. Is there another trick I could use to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct way to do it, unless you happen to own two Apple Thunderbolt displays you can daisy chain. What most people do is purchase a USB video adapter like a DisplayLink device. Performance and OS X support can be spotty but you might find something that'll work well, especially if you can get something with USB 3.0 support.

There are [plenty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/can-i-plug-two-external-monitors-in-to-a-macbook-pro?rq=1) [of related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7680/is-there-any-way-to-output-to-two-1920x1200-external-monitors-with-any-of-macboo?rq=1) [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46104/how-to-connect-two-non-thunderbolt-displays-to-the-macbook-pro-2011-via-thunderb?rq=1) in the sidebar --> that have more details on this.

Answer (score 1):

There's things like this - http://www.sonnettech.com/product/thunderbolt/index.html.
It's a Thunderbolt expansion chasis; you can put a video card in there. Don't know how it goes for drivers and they are fairly expensive. There's some others around.