# How can I connect 2 non apple screens to my 13" mac book pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I plug two external monitors in to a MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/can-i-plug-two-external-monitors-in-to-a-macbook-pro)

I've just purchased a new non-retina MacBook Pro 13" with the latest version of OS X (10.8.2).

I want to connect my two 22" displays (Samsung and LG) to my MBP and have a 3 screen workstation (laptop screen + 2 screens).

One external screen has got a VGA port and the other a DVI. The screen that has a VGA port has also got a DVI input.

Assuming I buy a VGA adapter that enables me to connect VGA to my MBP, could I connect my second screen to the first using the DVI port and see the 3 screens?

Comment: I don't think you can daisy chain the second screen to the first. Here are some previous questions regarding this issue: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/can-i-plug-two-external-monitors-in-to-a-macbook-pro and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3894/can-i-connect-more-than-one-external-monitor-to-the-late-2010-macbook-air

Comment: according to the [specs](http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/), you can only drive one external display - "Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an external display, both at millions of colors"

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is yes:

This should do it: http://www.iogear.com/product/GUC2015V/

As should this:

http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/searchtools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=6939907&SRCCODE=WEBGOOPA&cm_mmc_o=mH4CjC7BBTkwCjCV1-CjCE&gclid=CJyRgoSVp7MCFQ-f4AodtFAAHg

Comment: I've never seen good performance out of USB 2.0 display adapters.  Would a USB 3.0 version be any better?  If he got a new MacBook Pro it should have USB 3.0 ports.

Comment: I strongly recommend against this, they simply don't perform well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a Mini DisplayPort to DVI adaptor, these cost around 5 bucks on ebay. You plug it in your thunderbolt.
   http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-Displayport-Male-to-DVI-I-M-F-thunderbolt-Cable-Adapter-for-Apple-Macbook-/251063734918?pt=US_Video_Cables_Adapters&hash=item3a74909286
2. Use a DVI cable to link that adaptor to your monitor

Answer (score 0):

You will need a mini-display port to DVI adapter (for use with your thunderbolt port)

and

An HDMI to DVI cable (these are abundant and cheap)