# I have an IMac with 1 firewire and 1 mini DVI port, can I connect two additional monitors?

Tags: imac, display

I would like to connect two external monitors to my IMac (Mid 2010 with ATI Radeon HD 5750 1024 MB) I have one connected at the moment to the mini-dvi port, my question is: can I utilise the Firewire port to add a further monitor?

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3894/can-i-connect-more-than-one-external-monitor-to-the-late-2010-macbook-air

Comment: can't find any options for firewire, but if your monitor supports it you can daisy chain multiple screens together using display port cables. you can also look for a display port to multiple hdmi/dvi/vga splitter, but these are quite pricey

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not with what is built into the system. You would have to purchase an external adapter (usually USB) which can split the signal and act as a videocard/accelerator for a second display.

Comment: Thanks, I've located this piece of kit Matrox T2G-DP3D-IF Triplehead 2go looks to be ideal for what I require.